# What is wrong with my CSS menu?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, menu

The result is: http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/746/93502273.jpg

You can see the obvious "whitespace" on the side.

I have:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li id="n-home"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li id="n-search"><a href="/search/">Search</a></li>
        <li id="n-advertisers"><a href="/advertisers/">Advertisers</a></li>
        <li id="n-something"><a href="/something/">Something</a></li>
        <li id="n-contact"><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and

```
/* Navigation
---------------------------------------------------------- */

#nav {
    font-family: Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
#nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    width: 100%;
    }
#nav li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #f5f5f5; 
    }
#nav li a {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 1px 0 0;
    padding: 4px 9px;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #111;
    }

#nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    }
```

Comment: Can you give more details? What do you want your menu to look like? Looks fine to me, but I have no idea what you want from the menu.

Comment: There is a whitespace, the background of the menu does not stretch to the right side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try.

```
#nav li {
    display:inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #f5f5f5; 
}

#nav li a {
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 0 1px 0 0;
    padding: 4px 9px;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #111;
}
```

when you float items, the wrapper (in this case ul) cannot wrap around to display the background.

Another alternative is to do add to make the html like this:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li id="n-home"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li id="n-search"><a href="/search/">Search</a></li>
        <li id="n-advertisers"><a href="/advertisers/">Advertisers</a></li>
        <li id="n-something"><a href="/something/">Something</a></li>
        <li id="n-contact"><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="clear"> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and add this to the css:

```
#nav li.clear {
    float:none;
    clear:both;
    height:1px;
}
```

Comment: `inline-block` is not supported by all browsers.

Comment: Everything but IE6, and it would like similar enough to warrant this fix in every other browser (IE6 would have the space). IE7 supports it on items that are typically inline items.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your `<ul>` technically doesn't contain any content, as all the `<li>` elements are floating.  This means that the `<ul>` doesn't really have an "inside" to render.

The solution is as simple as adding `overflow:hidden` to your `#nav ul` style.  This is a clever work-around to what has been termed *the clearfix hack*.

Here's an interesting blog post [about the clearfix issue](http://perishablepress.com/press/2009/12/06/new-clearfix-hack/) if you want to read more about it.

Comment: blast! I always forget about that simple trick! I love the simplicity of it.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so you want the background of your Navigation Bar to stretch across the whole of your page, if I understand correctly.

First, you'd need to add `width:100%;` to your `#nav` declaration in your CSS file. Second, you might have to add `background-color: #f5f5f5;` as well, to keep the color consistency across the whole div, otherwise you won't be able to tell that it's stretching the whole way across.

Comment: #nav {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    } still leaves the whitespace

Comment: Well, why are you floating your list items and anchors? Just give a `display: inline;` to the list items and they should line up as they do currently, no?